# "Geometry exceeds allowed extent" error on displaying polygons with Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm displaying polygons with Mapbox GL JS from [GeoJSON](https://gist.github.com/vero4karu/b5019c0117876711b6570f188ee9fae8#file-fulfillment-geojson), where each feature has an extra field in properties called `color`. The value of that field defines the color of a polygon.

I have about 680 features, but when I'm running the JavaScript I get the following error:

```
Geometry exceeds allowed extent, reduce your vector tile buffer size
```

There is complete code of my app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.39.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.39.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'mapbox-token';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-74.07231699675322, 4.66336863727521],
    zoom: 12
});

map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource('fulfillment', {
      'type': 'geojson',
      'data': 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vero4karu/b5019c0117876711b6570f188ee9fae8/raw/54c9612d325eaca7e79fda74c405eb019ffdabf4/fulfillment.geojson'
    });

    map.addLayer({
      "id": "fulfillment-polygon",
      "type": "fill",
      "source": "fulfillment",
      "paint": {
        "fill-color": {
          property: 'color',
          type: 'identity'
        },
        "fill-opacity": 0.5
      }
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

mapbox-gl-js version: **v0.39.1**

Comment: Hi @vero4ka, I think this is a bug in the Mapbox vector tiles in this region and not in your code because the error is triggered even when your added source is not present.

Comment: @mollymerp might be right. You could open an issue at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/ where you link to this question. They might know whats going on.

Comment: @andi-lo this is not an issue with mapbox-gl-js but rather the tile source data. I opened an issue internally (I work at Mapbox) so we will investigate it!

Comment: Thanks @mollymerp! There is a similar issue at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/2779, so I commented there